# Xcode - saving constraints for the very end?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

Hi I'm fairly new to iOS development and I was wondering if it would be alright to save adding constraints to a project until the very end.  (Once I finish coding everything and having a rough layout of what I want it to look like)

Comment: you can adjust your UI for Iphone 4s screen (3.5 inch). And focus on implementation only , you can apply constraints to Fit UI for all screen sizes later .

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule that you should work with constraints at the time of coding but fixing view along side code will prevent massive amount of work later on related with layout on iPhone and iPad or even iPhone of different size.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder change the simulated metrics size to match what ever you are using for your development. Now nothing will need to resize and you should be good. Rotations will probably still cause issues though.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do it, but I would suggest either doing something a bit more "extreme" or not doing it at all.

If you start adding your assets, maybe animations or anything UI-related, you'll need those constraints. Testing on many devices sizes, sending betas, etc. All that will be easier with constraints. And constraints are really not that time consuming once you've got the hang of it. Also, I wouldn't consider starting a project if you don't know how it's gonna end ; that means you dont' have a valid design, you most probably don't have an analysis and this will not only cause UI issues. Once the people deciding start to add/modify features, it'll drive you crazy. A better idea is to have everything set in stone before writing the first line of code (or storyboard)

If all of the above is not an issue or irrelevant to your case, then by all means, you really can do it without any fear. And in that case, I suggest using bright colors and simple UI with almost-zero code in controllers to make sure you spend as little time as possible on the UI.

Focusing on " not doing the constraints " only is either too much or not enough. It's like saying you wanna build a house but you'll only paint the left side of the house to gain time. Don't paint it or paint it all, but don't half-ass it :P

I personally work like that for a specific project, we have the complete analysis with all features, but no design yet. It's "inspired" from another of their app, but still not certain. Right now I have all my buttons in the top left corner, all of automatic size with no fonts, no colors, nothing. It's just a big blob of buttons on all my views, and they pretty much all load from there.

This process helps speeding up your architecture, but you really need to be able to split UI from the rest in your head ; if you can do it, you'll probably have a much better and flexible architecture in the end, not couple to the UI at all.